# Grouping data in one table based on links in another table

Tags: mysql

I have something like this:

```
table1
ID   NAME

table2
ID   TABLE1_ID   NAME   VALUE

table3
ID   TABLE2_ID   COLLECTION
```

As you may be able to tell, multiple records from table2 can belong to a record in table1. table3 groups together multiple records in table2

It is no problem for me to loop through and display all of the table2 records for a given table1 record. How can I group those records based on table3 though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be by:

```
select * from table2 where id in (select table2_id from table3);
```